# how to calculate summary statistics and produce line plot for daily MODIS LST quality bands

Tags: python, raster, remote-sensing, modis

I have a raster stack (numpy 3d array) of daily MODIS LST quality bands.  The quality bands have pixel values that correspond to the quality of the LST data in each pixel.  For example, 2 = no data received due to clouds, 3 = possible cloud contamination, 17 = low quality for other reason, etc.

I would like to create a line plot (x axis = proportion of pixels, y axis = day of year) that depicts the proportion of pixels within the MODIS tile that have a given quality value on any day of the year.  The line plot would have multiple lines, each representing a value in the quality band.  I would like to do this in Python, if possible.

As an example, lets say I have a 2d array, which would represent a MODIS tile for one day, with the following information:
     [[2,3,0], [17,3,0], [2,2,0]]

For this array I would need to calculate the proportion of pixels that correspond to each value, and then have the output in some form (table or csv file) that I could then plot.  I would then repeat this process for each day of the year.

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of summing up the values for each layer and plotting, for instance with `matplotlib`?

Comment: @Kersten: thanks, I realized this question was too general and am trying to break down my tasks here: [link]http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167014/given-a-list-of-values-how-can-i-determine-the-proportion-of-raster-cells-that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [creation of the summaries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/167123/39299) from your other question the plotting can be done easily with `matplotlib`.

Given that the values you are looking for are in `val_list` and `results` is a nested list with the portion of values for each MODIS image.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(11,7))
for i, val in enumerate(val_list):
    plt.plot(np.array(results)[:,i], label="value %s" % val)
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

Here is how that would look for a time-series of the quality layer of the MOD13Q1 product.

[image]